# .HTACCESS: Getting a variable from text after a slash

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve something and I can't seem to quite figure it out.

I have a url of domain.com/page/variable

I currently have htaccess code to redirect domain.com/page to domain.com/page.php but I also want to send the second part as a get variable and I am unsure on how to achieve this.

Currently I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/forum [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

And that does my .php re-write perfectly, but how do I go about getting the second part as a get variable?

I tried adding the following but with no success

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?variable=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what error are you getting?

Comment: add this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$"` as a 3rd cond and append a "variable": `....php?variable=%1`